# Weird mysql query return values

Tags: mysql

I am trying to sum values from a tables column where some conditions are met but I can't figure out the returned values from mysql.

I have run the below script.

```
create table robot_data(name varchar(20), value float, x int, y int, z int);


insert into robot_data(name, value, x, y, z) values("temperature", 27.99, 1, 88, 0);
insert into robot_data(name, value, x, y, z) values("temperature", 27.99, 1, 88, 0);
insert into robot_data(name, value, x, y, z) values("temperature", 27.99, 1, 88, 0);
insert into robot_data(name, value, x, y, z) values("temperature", 27.99, 1, 88, 0);

insert into robot_data(name, value, x, y, z) values("humidity", 7.99, 1, 88, 0);
insert into robot_data(name, value, x, y, z) values("humidity", 7.99, 1, 88, 0);
insert into robot_data(name, value, x, y, z) values("humidity", 7.99, 1, 88, 0);
insert into robot_data(name, value, x, y, z) values("humidity", 7.99, 1, 88, 0);
insert into robot_data(name, value, x, y, z) values("humidity", 7.99, 1, 88, 0);
insert into robot_data(name, value, x, y, z) values("humidity", 7.99, 1, 88, 0);




SELECT  COUNT(temp.value) FROM 

(SELECT value, name from robot_data where name ='temperature') as temp,
(SELECT value, name from robot_data where name ='humidity') as hum;

SELECT COUNT(value) FROM robot_data;
```

I expect the first and second select to return the same results but they don't. The first one returns 24 and the second one 10 which is correct.

In reality what I want to do is this in the first select:

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(temp.value + hum.value))...
```

But I want none matching rows to return null since the values for temperature are 4 and humidity 6. I will appreciate if I can get an insight on what is happening.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: I have two expectations the first one is in the question but the answer below has clarified that it is essentially a table join this I did not know. The second one is to sum matching rows in temperature and humidity and null for rows without matching values so I will have 6 rows with the first four summing temp and humidity and the last one null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second return 10 because you have insert 10 rows in table robot_data

The first return 24 because your syntax

```
FROM ( ) temp, ( ) hum
```

produces a cross join between  the table returned by subquery from temperature of 4 rows and table return from subquery for humidity of 6 rows. So 6x4 = 24 rows.

Comment: Ok. This was insightful and I managed to solve my problem by using left joins.